# Qt Creator not sugggesting ui objects while typing

Tags: qt, autocomplete, qt-creator, qt6

Qt Creator is not suggesting code for `ui` items.

For example:

- `ui->lineEdit`
- `ui->pushButton`

I reinstalled Qt several times and it didn't help.

I'm using Linux Ubuntu 22, Qt Creator 10, Qt 6.4.2.

Below is an example, when typing `ui->` , there are no suggestions (drown down menu that suggests objects and methods).

[image]

Comment: Did you build the project? Contentents of `ui` are in a generated .h file, which is what thw C++ part of Qt Creator uses for completions.

Comment: How did you create the project?

Comment: In general, never include code as image, except if issue is about syntax highlighting or something which can't be represented as text only. I guess this case is borderline ok.

Comment: I created project by QTCreator, then build and run. Everything work ok. I have autocomplete code for example members or class what i have created but i dont have autocomplete hint for ui. I must say that ui prefix with methods work but it doesnt have autocomplete hint when i write it is just.

Comment: If you ctrl-click or press F2 to on the `ui`, and follow the chain, does Qt Creator take you to the generates .ui.h file?

Comment: ui files are generated and included . class is like Class::Class(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::FormClass)

Comment: is `ClangCodeModel` plugin installed and enabled (`Help->About plugins`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved. Missing ui was due to a wrongly set project path. Pay attention to it.
[image]